# MongoDB Array not displaying

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to query my MongoDB database to only fetch all the values in my array using my user_id

I have tried using the (schema.name), it not working out

```
// @route   GET api/user/package
// @desc    Get all package
// @access  Private
router.get('/package', 
  passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }),

 (req, res) => {
  Shipments.find({_id : req.user._id},{paymentStatus: "incomplete"})
    .then(shipments => res.status(200).json(shipments.packages))
    .catch(err =>res.status(404).json({ nopackages: 'No package found for you now' }));
});
```

Here is my expected result

```
"packages": [
    {
      "date": "2019-09-23T12:52:14.226Z",
      "_id": "5d88bffe2a6ed7b8d9873548",
      "category": "hazard",
      "quantity": "10",
      "description": "a valueablegoods",
      "length": 10,
      "height": 20,
      "width": 12,
      "weight": 12
    },
    {
      "date": "2019-09-23T12:52:58.129Z",
      "_id": "5d88c02a2a6ed7b8d9873549",
      "category": "hazard",
      "quantity": "10",
      "description": "a valueablegoods",
      "length": 10,
      "height": 20,
      "width": 12,
      "weight": 12
    }
  ],
```

but postman didn't return any value but brings a status 200, but returns nobody

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All i did was change find to findOne. This solve the problem

```
router.get('/package', 
  passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }),

 (req, res) => {
  Shipments.findOne({ $and: [{ _id : req.user._id }, { paymentStatus: "incomplete" }] })
    .then(shipments => res.status(200).json(shipments.packages))
    .catch(err =>res.status(404).json({ nopackages: 'No package found for you now' }));
});
```

it may help u

Comment: it only bring the whole info when i do ```.then(shipments => res.status(200).json(shipments))``` but if i do ```.then(shipments => res.status(200).json(shipments.packages))``` it return an empty body.

Answer (score 2):

Try `Shipments.findOne()`

This happens because you are getting a single user detail.

Comment: i already tried it joy but it is not working, so glad you are Nigerian lady.

Comment: Not that it is not working, it is not just returning the res.json of the package. but if i request for the shipment, it returns only the _id and the payment status